# Is there a way to map nested collections using ValueInjecter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dto, valueinjecter

I have an EF data structure which has data nested two levels deep, it looks roughly like this:

```
class Country {
    string Name {get; set;}
    ICollection<State> States {get; set;}
}

class State {
    string Name {get; set;}
    ICollection<County> Counties {get; set;}
}

class County {
     string Name {get; set;}
}
```

*Or: a country has states, and each state has counties.*

I've simplified much of the remote facade for this example so my DTO models are effectively the same structure here.  Using `ValueInjector` I'd like my code to look something like.

```
 var dbCountry = _dbContext.Countries.Find(id);
 var dtoCountry = new DTO.Country();
 dtoCountry.InjectFrom<FlatLoopInjection>(dbCountry);
 foreach (var dbState in dbCountry.States) {
    var dtoState= new DTO.State();
    dtoState.InjectFrom(dbState);
    dtoState.Counties = dbState
       .Counties
       .Select(m => new DTO.County().InjectFrom(m))
       .Cast<DTO.County>()
       .ToList();
    dtoCountry.States.Add(dtoState);
 }
```

The question is: is there a way to to this without the `foreach` loop?  Not that I'm anti-loop (and I'd love to start a holy war on this with the trolls), but this seems to mixing two patterns together (linq and loop).

Thanks.

Comment: have a read of this: https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter/blob/master/README.md, you can put the loop inside the `AddMap`